# Optimizing Django queries

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a page where users can see the comments list for a specific product.

In the view I get the list with:

`comments = product.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')`

and this piece in the template:

```
1   {% if comments %}
2       {% for comment in comments %}
3       <div class="comment">
4           <a href="/user/{{ product.author }}/">{{ comment.author }}</a>
5           <br>{{ comment.text }}
6       </div>
7       {% endfor %}
8   {% endif %}
```

Using django debug toolbar when I go to a product page I can see that Django performs many queries are many comments in the list. For example in a product page with a comments list of 10 comments, Django performs about 15 queries. If I submit a new comment, the queries count rises to 16.

If i try to remove `{{ comment.author }}` (line 4), the queries decrease to a fixed number, if I submit new comments. How to optimize this?

NB: `comment.author` is a ForeignKey to a `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to worry about optimization on this unless you're expecting 100's or 1000's of comments on each product. When you do this query, do you feel it takes too long to get those 10 comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a case for select_related?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Yes, I just found it. Awesome!